# How to do: After button pressed - current view will swap left, new view will come

Tags: android, view

I am a new android learner. I am working on an application project. In that project lets say I have an activity named MainActivity. In that activity's layout I have some radio groups and a button.

When this activity starts user can check those radio groups. if user press the button current view will be swiped left and a new view will appear which is actually the initial state of the previous view(Like radio buttons have been reset). Now user can check those radio groups again.

How can I do this.

Comment: use intents and try to code it

Comment: If you're not going to add some code, please add some illustrations about what you want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first create `RadioGroup` in layout and `Button`. Then in code set the next lines to your button `onCliclListener()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);

//In your coding use intent like for left to right:

YourClass.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter,
                   R.anim.animation_leave);
//    
//OR
//

//In your coding use intent like for right to left:

YourClass.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_leave,
                               R.anim.animation_enter);
```

And create animations:

Use this xml in `res/anim/`

This is for left to right animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

This is for right to left animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Also you can set the standart android animations:

```
YourClass.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

If you want another direction use this xml`s:

### anim_slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

### anim_slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your code I can see I have to pass two parameter in the overridePendingTransition() method, R.anim.animation_enter & R.anim.animation_leave. And you have provided two xml. Are these two xmls are for R.anim.animation_enter & R.anim.animation_leave? or I have create two animations myself?

Comment: You must create it with your hand. Don`t forget to vote up. :)

Comment: Thanks, It worked! Just one query ourClass.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right) swipes screen from left to right. How can I swipe right to left. I have tried altering two parameters, but didn't work. Is there any way to swipe from right to left from default animations?